# Replace string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to replace a string within an array with another string.
In my example `cat` should be replaced with `mouse`:

```
var arr1 = [ "dog", "cat"];

for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    arr1[i].replace("cat", "mouse");
}
```

Unfortunately, the array remains unchanged.

Where is the error?

Comment: Strings are immutable

Comment: @Oriol: Um, your link doesn't answer this question properly.  IMO, he should be using splice instead of replace, since it is an array question more than a straight string question.

    arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf('cat'), 1,'mouse');

Comment: @JohnGreen That replaces the first `'cat'` array entry with  `'mouse'`. Presumably, OP wants to replace the first `'cat'` substring of each string array entry with `'mouse'`. Not exactly the same.

Comment: @Oriol No, I'd have put it through a loop, which I had written up in my longer explanation before somebody closed the thread.  ; )

Comment: @JohnGreen Sorry, but I still think it's a dupe, because it asks why `replace` doesn't work, not ways of replacing. If you have an alternative code which solves the problem without `replace`, you can post a new self-answered question, and link it here in the comments.

Comment: @Oriol Eh, too much effort.  I will say that I think his question was tagged arrays, not replace.  His use of replace was just because he didn't think of splice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you need to reassign the result of the replace back to the element:

```
var arr1 = [ "dog", "cat"];

for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    arr1[i] = arr1[i].replace("cat", "mouse");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.replace()` returns a new string.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

So you should be doing.

`arr1[i] = arr[i].replace("cat", "mouse");`